# Programming Breakout with Racket

Tags: debugging, mouseevent, racket

I'm trying to program the breakout game (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hW7Sg5pXAok) using DrRacket (BSL). I started by writing the code for the bar controlled by the player. The bar should move alongside with the mouse until following the x-Axis and stay immobile on the y-Axis. My code is the following, the bar is moving but the mouse-event doesn't seem to work, can you help debug it ?

```
(require 2htdp/universe)
(require 2htdp/image)

(define-struct playerState (locPlayer))
(define playerRectangle (rectangle 20 10 "solid" "red"))
(define playerScene (empty-scene 200 200))

; WorldState -> Image
; draws a player's state to an image
(check-expect (drawPlayer (make-playerState (make-posn 50 99))) (place-image playerRectangle 50 99 playerScene))
(define (drawPlayer state)
(place-image playerRectangle (posn-x (playerState-locPlayer state)) (posn-y (playerState-locPlayer state)) playerScene))

; WorldState -> WorldState
; computes a new player worldstate after a clock tick
(check-expect (tickPlayer (make-playerState (make-posn 50 99))) (make-playerState (make-posn 51 99)))
(define (tickPlayer state)
(make-playerState (make-posn (+ 1 (posn-x (playerState-locPlayer state))) (posn-y (playerState-locPlayer state)))))

; mouseEvent -> WorldState
; computes a new player worldstate if the mouse is moved
(define (mouse state x y mouse-event)
(cond [(string=? mouse-event "move")
  (cond
    [(> x (posn-x (playerState-locPlayer state))) (make-playerState (make-posn (+ 1 (posn-x (playerState-locPlayer state))) (posn-y (playerState-locPlayer state))))]
    [(< x (posn-x (playerState-locPlayer state))) (make-playerState (make-posn (- 1 (posn-x (playerState-locPlayer state))) (posn-y (playerState-locPlayer state))))])]
  [else (make-playerState (make-posn (posn-x (playerState-locPlayer state)) (posn-y (playerState-locPlayer state))))]))


 (define (main state)
 (big-bang state (to-draw drawPlayer) (on-mouse mouse) (on-tick tickPlayer)))

(define initialPlayer (make-playerState (make-posn 100 199)))
(main initialPlayer)
```

Comment: I recommend not using nested conditional statements, As it is easier to make complicated mistakes that are hard to take back. For example the else state that is missing is fatal which i described earlier if you were to to cross from the first condition to the other you would encounter an error as there is no else when x is equivalent to the posn of player-state

Comment: 1 thing I do recommend instead of nested conditionals is the use of `and` or `or` these are pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

Some things i see here is your tick-handler. This does not need to update the players position if you want the mouse-handler to update the player position so for now you can take that out. From now on when you type i suggest you indent on every half screen, this makes it look more managed. Now the problem with your on-mouse handler is simple. While it is deciding which way you are moving the mouse it confuses itself and makes some really interesting decisions. At the same time if you were to start on the right-hand side of the screen and drag the mouse to the left it will result in an error. So to fix this i decided to do this.

```
(define (mouse state x y mouse-event)
(cond [(string=? mouse-event "move")
     (make-playerState
      (make-posn (- 200 x);200 is the width of the screen
                 (posn-y (playerState-locPlayer state))))]
    [else state]))
```

All this does is give the reversed control to the player. That is what i interpreted, from playing what you had posted.